# How do I get markdown to display tables in octopress

Tags: markdown, blogs, octopress

I'm using markdown in Octopress and I'm following this cheat sheet https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Here-Cheatsheet#tables

Here is the table I'm trying to create with markdown

```
|id | name | height | created_at | updated_at|
|---|------|--------|------------|-----------|
| fd| df   |dfd     |  dfdfd     |dfdfdfd |
```

It doesn't seem to do it's markdown magic. I just get this

```
id  name    height  created_at  updated_at
fd  df  dfd dfdfd   dfdfdfd
```

It says something in the guide about GFM and Markdown Here

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Comment: Have you switched your markdown processor?  Octopress does not use Github-flavored markdown by default, and the guide mentions that tables are not in the core markdown spec.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this thread that considers some hacks. But out of the box markdown (with normal processors) does not offer any way to create a table: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables

Depending on what you are trying to do though, you might be able to use the [html table syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html).

Answer (score 0):

Try html tables: [W3Schools HTML Tables](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same syntax for table as Kramdown. Octopress uses Jekyll which in turn uses [Kramdown](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/2b30c0614017d4805f368a279c88262f200a1f59/jekyll.gemspec#L33) internally to render markdown. Kramdown allows various syntaxes for defining tables, described at https://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#tables

[image: Kramdown table syntax example]